# Unable to understand the type casting done in the inet_ntoa function

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion, inet

I am understanding the `gethostbyname()` function.
At that time I found the following sample program.

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *host, **names, **addrs;
    struct hostent *hostinfo;

    if(argc == 1) 
    {
        char myname[256];
        gethostname(myname, 255);
    host = myname;
    }
    else
    host = argv[1];

    hostinfo = gethostbyname(host);
    if(!hostinfo) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot get info for host: %s\n", host);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("results for host %s:\n", host);
    printf("Name: %s\n", hostinfo -> h_name);
    printf("Aliases:");
    names = hostinfo -> h_aliases;
    while(*names) 
    {
        printf("%s", *names);
        names++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    if(hostinfo -> h_addrtype != AF_INET) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "not an IP host!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    addrs = hostinfo -> h_addr_list;
    while(*addrs) 
    {
        printf(" %s", inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)*addrs));
        addrs++;
    }
printf("\n");
exit(0);
}
```

now I run it on my system.
It is working fine. There are two things which are confusing me:

1. In the **inet_ntoa** function, we have type case it like `inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)*addrs)`.
   But If we do the type case like `inet_ntoa((struct in_addr) addrs)`.Then It is not working.
   I am not able to understand the reason behind this. Please also explain me that what kind of type casting is done here.
2. When I am understanding this program. I am also not able to understand the following while loop.

   while(*addrs) 
   {
       printf(" %s", inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)*addrs));
       addrs++;
   }

   Please explain me about it.
3. Suppose there is a one **`char**test`** which is pointing to string "india". When Ever we done something like `test++`. It is incremented according to the string size. In this case It will be incremented by 6(5 + 1(null char.)). Why so?

Comment: There are significant differences between `*(struct in_addr *)*addrs` and `(struct in_addr) addrs`. Why would you expect them to be equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

> I. In the inet_ntoa function, we have type case it like inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)*addrs). But If we do the type case like inet_ntoa((struct in_addr) addrs).Then It is not working. I am not able to understand the reason behind this. Please also explain me that what kind of type casting is done here.

For this you've to know what is the definition of the type `in_addr` is. From MSDN

```
typedef struct in_addr {
  union {
    struct {
      u_char s_b1,s_b2,s_b3,s_b4;
    } S_un_b;
    struct {
      u_short s_w1,s_w2;
    } S_un_w;
    u_long S_addr;
  } S_un;
} IN_ADDR, *PIN_ADDR, FAR *LPIN_ADDR;

Members:
S_un
    S_un_b: An IPv4 address formatted as four u_chars.
    S_un_w: An IPv4 address formatted as two u_shorts.
    S_addr: An IPv4 address formatted as a u_long.
```

Here the structure has a union out of which our interest is in `chars`. Since `addrs` is of type `char**` when we do `*addrs` we get `char*` which is the decayed type of `char` array. In the type cast we manually convert `char*` to `struct in_addr*`. But [inet_ntoa](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738564%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) takes an `in_addr` object by value and not reference. Thus we add another * to the casted type to change it from  `in_addr*` to `in_addr`. Without the case doing `**addrs` would give a `char` and not a `in_addr`.

> II. while(*addrs) { printf(" %s", inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)*addrs)); addrs++; }

To understand this loop you've see where you load `addrs` from: `struct hostent::h_aliases` which again MSDN documents as

```
A NULL-terminated array of alternate names.
```

`addrs` is pointing to an array of character sequences (strings) with a terminating NULL element. For e.g. `char *addrs[] = { "Delhi", "London", "New York", NULL };` We know that `addrs` is non-null, but `*addrs` will be non-null only thrice, the fourth element would be NULL when checked as `while(*addrs)`.

> III. Suppose there is a one char**test which is pointing to string "india". When Ever we done something like test++. It is incremented according to the string size. In this case It will be incremented by 6(5 + 1(null char.)). Why so?

Wrong! `char **test = "india";` is illegal. However, like I've explained above, it'll be pointing to an array of such strings. When you do a `addrs++`, what really happens is not incremented based on the string length but just increment by an element. When you do `*addrs` it'll point to "Delhi", then `addrs++` and `*addrs` will now point to "London" and so on.

I would recommend that you read [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) for details on array to pointer decay, pointer arithmetic, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1> The  inet_ntoa()  function converts the Internet host address in, given
       in network byte order, to a string  in  IPv4  dotted-decimal  notation.
       The  string  is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which subse‐
       quent calls will overwrite.

Prototype of int_ntoa  :

```
 char *inet_ntoa(struct in_addr in);
```

This line which you are writing "`inet_ntoa((struct in_addr) addrs)`" is wrong.
As in your code addr is double pointer . you are type casting  address to "in_addr object" which is wrong.

The line `*(struct in_addr *)*addrs` or `* ( (struct in_addr *)*addrs )` means :

1.> convert value of `*addr` ( which is again a address ) to "`struct in_addr *`" i.e. "`in_addr *`" type.

2.> And `* ( (struct in_addr *)*addrs )` means object/value of in_addr type.

2.> Second :

```
 addrs = hostinfo -> h_addr_list;
    while(*addrs) 
    {
        printf(" %s", inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)*addrs));
        addrs++;
    }
```

Here , hostinfo -> h_addr_list returns pointer to  array i.e its address of first element.

`addrs++` means moving to next elemnt in the arry. when array is finished `*addr` will be null.

`inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)*addrs` , this will convert all  byte address to string.